# Does celery max_memory_per_child work within chains or chords?

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a memory leak issue in an app that I cannot fix so I have addressed it by using `CELERY_WORKER_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD` in my django app settings. It appears to be working in that workers that reach the memory limit are reset, but those workers are part of a group within a chain that looks like:

```
chain(setup | group(job1, job2) | call_back)()
```

After a worker hits the memory limit while processing one of the jobs within the `group` it appears that the `call_back` never gets called because the `celery.chord_unlock` loops indefinitely.  Does the `CELERY_WORKER_MAX_MEMORY_PER_CHILD` only work with individual tasks? (And not within chains or chords?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The max memory per child configuration setting most likely works.

I suspect one of the two possibilities here:

1. A task, or tasks that are executed as part of your Chord reached maximum number retries.
2. There is an issue with Chord (a bug) that prevents callback from being called.

Run your workers with DEBUG or INFO log-level, and see what is going on.

Comment: Running with INFO log-level showed that sometimes a task gets killed due to a SEGFAULT, which (I guess) is not handled by the Celery Task on_failure method (i.e. the worker is killed but the chord is not aware of the failure).